# Neo4j more specific query slower than more generic one

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to count all values collected in one subtree of my graph. I thought that the more descriptive path from the root node I provide, the faster the query will run. Unfortunately this isn't true in my case and I can't figure out why.

Original, slow query:

```
MATCH (s:Sandbox {name: "sandbox"})<--(root)-[:has_metric]->(n:Metric)-[:most_recent|:prev*0..]->(v:Value) return count(v)
```

[image: Slower query] PROFILE returns `38397 total db hits in 2203 ms.`

However without matching top-level node, labeled `Sandbox`, query is 10 times faster:

```
MATCH (root)-[:has_metric]->(n:Metric)-[:most_recent|:prev*0..]->(v:Value) return count(v)
```

[image: Faster query] PROFILE returns `38478 total db hits in 159 ms`

To make this clear, in this case the result is the same as I have just one Sandbox.

What is wrong in my first query? How should I model/query the hierarchy like that? I can save sandbox name as property in Metric node, but it seems uglier for me, however executes faster.

Comment: Did you try the first query multiple times? Sometimes a query can take more time than normal, depending on how busy the server is at the moment and other factors. So, to verify the performance you should try a query multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I did, I've made a lot of tests and the results are repeatable.

Comment: Does the root node have a lot of relationships ? Maybe it would be good to add relationship type to Sandbox, so that it does not expand all relationships.

Comment: Root node has a lot of relationships, but only one in "up" direction so I've thought that relationship type doesn't change anything here.  However you're right, type improves the query time (~300ms), but still it's never as fast as the second query (<200ms). Maybe now this is just the measurement error?

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2 queries are not identical.

(For reader visual difference)

```
MATCH (s:Sandbox {name: "sandbox"})<--(root)-[:has_metric]->(n:Metric)-[:most_recent|:prev*0..]->(v:Value) return count(v)
MATCH                                 (root)-[:has_metric]->(n:Metric)-[:most_recent|:prev*0..]->(v:Value) return count(v)
```

So in the second query, Neo4j doesn't care about (root). You never use root, and root is already implied by [:has_metric], so Neo4j can just skip to finding `()-[:has_metric]->(n:Metric)-[:most_recent|prev]`. In the first query, now we also have to find these Sandbox nodes! And on top of that, root has to be connected to that too! So Neo4j has to do extra work to prove that that is true. The extra column can also add more rows to the results being processed, which may add more validation checks on the rest of the query.

So long story short, the first query is slower because it is doing more validation work. So, the first query will be a subset of the latter.

Comment: But in my case there is just 1 sandbox node. Is it enough to make my query 10 times slower? I'm surprised!

Comment: @Spec You are adding a check for additional nodes connected to root in any way, and then checking all of those nodes that at least one of them is a Sandbox node. Even worse, you are bringing another column into the results, so the final number of rows will be multiplied by average number of Sandbox nodes, so all further checks have to also do more work.